# swiftui list with custom image header

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to set a image header for list in swiftui. The effect I want is shown in the figure below:

[image]

My code is as bellow:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section() {
                    VStack() {
                        Image("HeadImage")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        Text("Test word")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 150)
                }
                ForEach((0..<4), id: \.self) { index in
                    Section {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("aaa")) {
                            Label("Buttons", systemImage: "capsule")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("aaa")) {
                            Label("Colors", systemImage: "paintpalette")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("aaa")) {
                            Label("Controls", systemImage: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .accentColor(.accentColor)
    }
}
```

The result is as bellow, the header view has a white background:

[image]

I find a method to set the image row backgroud color as bellow:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section() {
                    VStack() {
                        Image("HeadImage")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        Text("Test word")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    // rgb get from screenshot of List in Sketch
                    .background(Color(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 247/255))
                }
                ForEach((0..<4), id: \.self) { index in
                    Section {
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("aaa")) {
                            Label("Buttons", systemImage: "capsule")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("aaa")) {
                            Label("Colors", systemImage: "paintpalette")
                        }
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("aaa")) {
                            Label("Controls", systemImage: "slider.horizontal.3")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .accentColor(.accentColor)
    }
}
```

This can make the image row to same background color with the List.

But this way is to set a fixed color, which is the RGB value of the background color of the List obtained by using the color finder in Sketch. It is not a very beautiful method. Is there a more elegant way to set the background color of the image row to be the same as the background color of the List?

Comment: I am a bit lost in your question here. Your description, image, and question title do not match with each other at all. Can you edit and let us know again what do you want exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done making list row background transparent, like

```
Section() {
    VStack() {
        Image("HeadImage")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        Text("Test word")
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)

    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    .frame(height: 150)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)     // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: This works nice but not when there is a shadow going outside the bounds of the before visible grouped clip shape. Any ideas how to get rid of that? 
In other words the `rowInset = .none` and `frame.maxWidth = .infinity` don't ensure the full width.

Comment: Found the solution. Rather a hack but works: Creating an empty Section and putting the views inside the header of that section
`Section() {  VStack() {}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).listRowInsets(.none) .listRowBackground(Color.clear)} header: { YourView() }`